# OpenSSO sample applications?

Tags: opensso

Do you know any good sample applications to demonstrate how a webapplication is added to use OpenSSO?

Comment: Can you be more specific... What kind of application? What are you trying to do - provide SSO within your enterprise, or do inter-domain SSO with SAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hard part is to setup and configure the OpenSSO/OpenAM server. This is an important part if you want to [add SSO to a website by using OpenAM](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Add+Authentication+to+a+Website+using+OpenAM). The simplest example I know is this site about [Integrating Applications With OpenSSO](http://developers.sun.com/identity/reference/techart/app-integration.html), where the SSO server sets a cookie if the user is logged in. It is an older site from Sun, but the Ruby on Rails example still works (with Rails 2.3.x or 3.0.x). I only had to replace

```
req['Cookie'] = token_cookie
```

in line 61 and 79 by

```
req['Cookie'] = token_cookie_name+"="+token_cookie
```

where token_cookie_name is the name of the cookie returned by the function `get_cookie_name_for_token()`. Working with SAML is a bit more complicated.